# Replace 0 with data from another cell

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a sheet to track my revenue for my business, I want to make one cell that has this formula:

```
=IF(J2="","",J2*C2)
```

I use this formula to calculate the total revenue on my product, so if `J2*C2` = `0` I want to change 0 with data from another cell `B` for example I spent `5$` on ads and didn't get any sale I want to get `-$5` result in the cell that calculates the total revenue.

Can someone help me to make it happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just add another `IF` there like:

```
=IF(J2="", , IF(J2*C2=0, B2*-1, J2*C2))
```

[image: j]